# Change LUKS Passphrase Prompt

Tags: customization, plymouth, luks

How would one go about customizing the LUKS passphrase prompt when decrypting drive at system startup? I am on 16.04. Have looked into `/lib/cryptsetup/cryptdisks`.functions. Have also checked Plymouth. I cannot locate the output source. `grep` isn't helping either. I have scoured the web and have not seen any viable solutions other than recompiling from source.

Comment: It is in the initrd

Answer (score 1):

It is in the [`initrd.img`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_ramdisk). On `/scripts/local-top/cryptroot`.